# Sending image to SOAP webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

I am trying to send some texts and an image. I can send everything except the image. The problem is I dont know how to pass it.

in .net soap webservice, image is declared as base64binary. what is the equalevant in objective c ? how should I pass it in objective c ?

here is my code (I am sending an empty string for image, this code works but inserts nothing for image column)

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<insert_data xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<id>%@</id>"
                         "<name>%@</name>"
                         "<lname>%@</lname>"
                         "<date>%@</date>"
                         "<image1>%@</image1>"
                         "</insert_data>"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n",@"999",@"arif",@"yilmaz",@"2013-09-09",@""];


  (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {
 [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
[popoverController release];

NSString *mediaType = [info
                       objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    UIImage *image = [info
                      objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    /* Setting the images to the correct viewer - AY */
    if(image_counter==0){
        imageView.image = image;
        *datax = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);   
        //********* I am getting the error here
        // "Assigning to 'NSData' from incompatible type NSData * "
    }
    else if(image_counter==1){
        imageView2.image = image;
    }
    else{
        imageView3.image = image;
    }
    if(image_counter<3)
        image_counter++;
    /******************/

    if (newMedia)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                       self,
                                       @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                       nil);
}
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
{
    // Code here to support video if enabled
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901797/iphone-uiimage-upload-to-web-service

Comment: You can use third party frameworks such as AFNetwork. AFNetworking makes post very easy.

Comment: I need to send it as base64binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this one. Here give your image and send your image's data to server.

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<insert_data xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<id>%@</id>"
                         "<name>%@</name>"
                         "<lname>%@</lname>"
                         "<date>%@</date>"
                         "<image1>%@</image1>"
                         "</insert_data>"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n",@"999",@"arif",@"yilmaz",@"2013-09-09",data];
```

Edited .....

Remove pointer variable from here...

```
  datax = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Comment: it says "Assigning to 'NSData' from incompatible type NSData * " , is it because I am trying to get the image from camera?

Comment: thank you very much. I marked it as answered. thanks for the effort

Comment: do you know how can i receive this image in .net ?

Comment: @etab Sorry boss i don't have any idea about .net .